# How to print wide character string?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

The ISO-10646 code point value of Cyrillic lowercase a is 0x430, so I tried the following:

```
char u8str[] = u8"Cyrillic lowercase a is: \u0430.";
cout << u8str;
```

and

```
wchar_t wstr[] = L"Cyrillic lowercase a is: \u0430.";
wcout << wstr;
```

The Cyrillic lowercase a is successfully printed through `u8str`, but not `wstr`.

As for `u8str`, I've confirmed that its storage is initialized with the utf-8 encoding values of those characters (the Cyrillic lower case a occupies 2 bytes with the value `D0 B0`).  All seems alright.  The Cyrillic got printed correctly.

As for `wstr`, I suppose that each `wchar_t` in the `wstr` array is initialized with the numerical value of the encoding of the character in the execution wide-character set.  While I don't fully understand what `execution wide-character set` is, I checked that the value of the Cyrillic lowercase a stored in the array is `0x430`.  Anyway, the Cyrillic letter doesn't get printed correctly.  (Other characters are all OK.)

I'm a total novice for `wchar_t` stuffs, so my apology if this question is too elementary.  What went wrong in my attempt printing the Cyrillic letter using wide character string?  Is it an issue of the letter's representation in the execution wide-character set (what is this character set after all)?  Or is it an issue about the incorrect usage of iostream facilities?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/

> A program should not mix output operations on cout with output operations on wcout (or with other wide-oriented output operations on stdout): Once an output operation has been performed on either, the standard output stream acquires an orientation (either narrow or wide) that can only be safely changed by calling freopen on stdout.

So only use one of the two.

Comment: I actually ran the two cases separately.  They were put together in the question just for convenience.  Sorry for not being clear on this.

Comment: Well you need to enable Unicode for your application.
For MSVC you can use     _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); at the start of your main.
But for mingw this is a bit more difficult, see here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Unicode%20apps

Comment: Does it mean that it's more of a problem on the iostream facility but not the execution wide-character set representation of the Greek letter?

Comment: As for execution character set, it's quite clear to me.  It's almost always utf-8 on Linux.  On Windows, it's Windows-1252 if system locale is set to English and other encoding for other locale (e.g. cp936 for Chinese).  These can be easily observed by checking the byte content of a char array such as: `char str[] = "Greek lowercase alphs is: \u03B1.";`  But for execution wide-character set, I don't understand much.

Comment: It seems that the ISO-10646 value 0x3B1 always gets stored in the wchat_t array for a declaration like: `wchar_t wstr[] = L"Greek lowercase alphs is: \u03B1.";`, so I guess the execution wide-charater set may well be UCS-2/UCS-4 (different environment have different size for wchar_t).  But I never managed to print the wide character array successfully.